How to get the TextMateScope of the word under the cursor in an extension
The command Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes is able to show the TextMate Scope (keyword/comment/literal/punctuation/...) of the word/token at the cursor location (line:char).
Can I get this same info in an extension?

VSCode does not give access to the built-in tokens.
Because the parser runs on the render thread and not the extension host thread.
You can instead use the same VSCode TextMate library to parse files and receive the tokens.
Otherwise you could use Web-Tree-Sitter.
I've implemented both in my extension.

how would tree sitter help get textmate scopes?

Depends if he specifically needs TextMate tokens vs just the language tokens. @starball

the question is pretty clear
